# Twitter Search API rate limit

Tags: twitter

I'm using the Twitter search API (for example: http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=%23juventus&rpp=100&page=4)

I read here: http://search.twitter.com/api/ this:

> We do not rate limit the search API under ordinary circumstances, however we have put measures in place to limit the abuse of our API. If you find yourself encountering these limits, please contact us and describe your app's requirements.

The limit seems random: sometimes I do 150 requests sometimes 300, generally, after 5 minutes I can do other requests.

I was wondering if is it possible do more requests

Answer (score 0):

They'll detect floods and throttle accordingly rather than publisher defined limits, which is why it appears random. It'll also no doubt be based on load from other sources at the time.

If you need lots more, then they gave you the answer - contact them telling them why.